# Vagrant file access issues with NFS

Tags: twig, nfs, vagrant

I'm running vagrant with an Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS box. The local folder on my Mac is mounted with NFS and all works fine except for one thing.

I'm developing a PHP project which uses Twig as template system but whenever I modify a template on my Mac and save it, it required two refreshes before Twig can load the template. The first refresh i'm getting an exception telling me that the file cannot be found. the second refresh is fine and the template loads just fine.

When switching back from NFS to the default VirtualBox filesystem all is fine but my dev site become terribly slow, almost to the point it's unworkable.

Anyone has an idea in what direction to look or has a clear solution?

[image: The thrown exception]

Comment: NFS under vagrant (especially with VirtualBox) is known to be terribly slow..

Comment: I have this exact issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?